# Toshiba C55D memory upgrade?

Tags: memory

I have a Toshiba C55D-B5310 and I've been trying to upgrade the ram to 8gb.

The Toshiba website doesn't give any extensive information about memory compatibility and states that it is not user upgradable. However, this is false.

The original ram in the computer is

Samsung 4gb 1Rx8 PC3L-12800s-11-13-B4

I found a couple online but im not sure of the voltage that's compatible with the pc.

Can anyone please help with this issue.

Comment: Upgradeable RAM is a selling point and non-upgradeable RAM would detract from sales.  I wouldn't expect Toshiba to claim it is non-upgradeable if it really is.  Sometimes, it is non-upgradeable either because it is soldered in rather than using sockets, or because it is in a location where you would void the warranty if you disassembled it to gain access.  So what makes you think it is user-upgradeable (out of warranty and you already disassembled it)?

Comment: I opened the laptop up already.  There are two ram slots only one is used.  I purchased a ram card but it had the wrong voltage.     http://m.toshibadirect.com/product/detail/computers/laptops/satellite/C50/C55D-B5310

Comment: Why not call Toshiba tech support and ask them what makes it "non-upgradeable" and what RAM the factory would use to upgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

1Rx8 means the memory chips are on one side of the RAM module.
1R and 2R refer to the number of memory ranks on the module. Dual-rank (2R) modules appear to the system as if two memory modules were inserted in that memory channel, which may cause compatibility issues if you have multiple such modules on the same channel.

Coming to the PC3 and PC3L part, PC3 RAMs requires an operating voltage of 1.5V whereas PC3L requires an operating voltage of 1.35V. The 'L' in PC3L signifies Low Voltage. So using PC3 RAM in a PC3L RAM slot will not provide it sufficient voltage and it will fail to operate. On the other hand using a PC3L RAM in a PC3 RAM slot may damage it due to overvoltage. So PC3 and PC3L RAMs are not compatible with each other.

The first 11 is the CAS timing. The second 13 is the version of Serial Presence Detect (SPD) used for communication between the RAM module and the computer. The B3/B4 is the reference design file used for this design and Revision number of the reference design used.

Crucial.com can help you with any Ram or Hard Disk upgrade.